# did I accidentally create a vba race condition?

Tags: vba, excel

I was hoping for some insight on a bug that I haven't been able to replicate.

I have a very complicated worksheet that changes many variables to get a certain cell `aa5`  to return a string. if any condition is not met, it returns `0`. the formula for that cell is

```
=IF(SUM(AA2:AA4)=0,SubItem,0)
```

where `aa2:aa4` are the conditions which must be 0 to return a string and `subitem` is a named cell range.

Once it returns a string, I have a module to paste the cell `aa5` onto a different sheet `export`. The problem is that after I run the routine, (it takes about 20 min) I find 0 values in the `export` sheet.

I have tried manually changing all the variables to the condition that created the error and none appears. I've also tried running through the code line-by-line and can't seem to replicate it there either.

My last straw was inserting in the module that pastes into `export` sheet

```
If Worksheets("analysis").Range("aa5").Value = 0 Then
Exit Sub
```

And still I have 0 values after running!

I am not really a programmer but I have some experience with VBA code, is it possible I've created a race condition where the 0 is copied before the `if` is updated but it still passes the vba check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to calculate your value before using it in VBA:

```
With Worksheets("analysis").Range("aa5")
    .Calculate
    If .Value <> 0 Then
        Worksheets("export").Range("A1").Value = .Value
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I ran this and it works, I will try a few more times before accepting.  I would assume that the cell would be calculated at the time of the `if` in vba. Any idea why this could not be the case?

Comment: I try to guess that your workbook has many formulas and recalculation takes some time. VBA doesn't wait the end of recalculation untill you call `.Calculate` explicitly. Another possible issue - you may have manual calculation mode for you workbook